# Can embedded videos be CSS transformed?

Tags: css, flash, video, transform, html5-video

I'm experimenting with CSS transforms and I noticed that embedded videos (like for instances the ones from youtube) don't behave as expected when a CSS transformation is applied to them.

I've tested this in the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE and none of them was able to display transformed videos.

Is this a bug of sort, or are videos not supposed to obey to CSS transformations? Not even using html5 in Chrome solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do of course. I created a few examples on my book's website [HTML5 Multimedia: Develop and Design](http://html5multimedia.com) under 'chapter 7'.

Here's a [video undergoing a 3d rotation](http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch7/css-animation-spin-rotate.html) (Chrome and Safari only - hover over it).

Comment: It must be something they added recently to Chrome, since at the time I asked the question it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely you can transform video due to the complexity and processing overhead it would introduce. Computers like to display video in nice rectangular areas which can be reserved and passed directly to display hardware.

The same applies to plugins like Flash and Java.

In short, even if you could do this it's unlikely the result would be watchable except on very high end PCs.

It's possible that one day WebGL will allow mapping video into 3D spaces using hardware acceleration but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a solution.

BTW, if you video is simple enough you might find converting the video to an animated GIF solves the issue.

Comment: Well, from an implementation point of view a framebuffer could be used or a 3d surface. No specially powerful machine would be needed for that, BeOS could do realtime 3d video transformations something like 10 years ago. What does the standard say about this, though? Are videos supposed to be transformed as well, or are they not?